# What movie has miners release a monster with thermal vision that hunts a trucker?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

About a year ago, I was watching a movie and I can't remember the name. A group of miners released a monster that uses thermal vision to find the victims. The movie follows a trucker as he tries to survive. The monster chases the trucker and the other survivors he picked up down to a cabin owned by an old couple. The old couple is killed by the monster and the survivors struggle to survive. I believe it was set in Alaska but am not positive. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site! If the answer below answers your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the check-mark to the left of the answer. That way other users don't have to keep searching for answers, *and* it rewards the person who found your answer for you. :)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like [Ice Road Terror](https://abyssalvault.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/ice-road-terror/)

> Two truckers driving across frozen Alaskan rivers to deliver equipment to a remote diamond mine, encounter a long-dormant prehistoric creature on the frozen ice.
>  
>   <sub>- [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1657285/)</sub>

[image]